# While Mail body being received, how to fetch the Image from multipart body

Tags: ckeditor, jakarta-mail, mime-message, mime-mail

My application actually has mail send / receive functionalities to handle.

While receiving the mail, i am unable to view the image which is an inline image being sent from outlook.

Can some one help me how can i catch the image and make available always.

I have java code like below,

```
try (InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64
            .getMimeDecoder().decode(mail))) {

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(null, stream);
        Object messageContent = message.getContent();
        if (messageContent instanceof String) {
            body = (String) messageContent;
        } else if (messageContent instanceof MimeMultipart) {
            content = (MimeMultipart) messageContent;
            for (int i = 0; i < content.getCount(); i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = content.getBodyPart(i);
                String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();

                if (disposition == null
                        || disposition
                                .equalsIgnoreCase(Part.INLINE)) {
                    Object object = bodyPart.getContent();
                    if (object instanceof String) {
                        body = object.toString();
                    } else if (object instanceof MimeMultipart) {
                        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) object;
                        String plainBody = null;
                        String htmlBody = null;

                        for (int j = 0; j < mimeMultipart.getCount(); j++) {
                            BodyPart multipartBodyPart = mimeMultipart
                                    .getBodyPart(j);
                            String multipartDisposition = multipartBodyPart
                                    .getDisposition();
                            String multipartContentType = multipartBodyPart
                                    .getContentType();
                            if (multipartDisposition == null
                                    && multipartContentType != null) {
                                if (multipartContentType
                                        .contains(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)) {
                                    htmlBody = multipartBodyPart
                                            .getContent().toString();
                                } else if (multipartContentType
                                        .contains(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                                    plainBody = multipartBodyPart
                                            .getContent().toString();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (htmlBody != null) {
                            body = htmlBody;
                        } else {
                            body = plainBody;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Client side i am using CKEditor to handle email body data.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got a solution from the example shared below

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_fetching_emails.htm

But, this example explains, how to find the image in body and store.
I have also done below to replace src

`
Pattern htmltag = Pattern.compile("]*src=\"[^>]*>(.*?)");
Pattern link = Pattern.compile("src=\"[^>]*\">");
String s1 = "";

```
    Matcher tagmatch = htmltag.matcher(s1);
    List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (tagmatch.find()) {
        Matcher matcher = link.matcher(tagmatch.group());
        matcher.find();
        String link1 = matcher.group().replaceFirst("src=\"", "")
                .replaceFirst("\">", "")
                .replaceFirst("\"[\\s]?target=\"[a-zA-Z_0-9]*", "");
        links.add(link1);
        s1 = s1.replaceAll(link1, "C:\\//Initiatives_KM\\//image.jpg");            

    }
```

`

And on top of this, i gonna do Base64 encoding so that i dont require store in file system.

`encodedfileString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bArray);`

With all these i can conclude to say, i got solution for my issue. Thank you.